# Memory Management of UnManaged Objects

Tags: memory, clr, unmanaged

I have one query regarding release of unmanaged objects. As unmanaged objects are not directly under control of CLR so CLR can't release it directly and for that we call dispose command but if we didn't use dispose command in our application for that unmanaged object then how resource occupied by that objects will release .

For Ex. If in C# code I am using connection objects as

```
try
{
    string strConnectionString = "";
    strConnectionString = "Server=FTSPROD\\FTS_PROD;Database=tdps_uat;User ID=txnapp;password=txnapp;Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=10000;";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {              
        SqlConnection cnUpdateTransaction;                    
        cnUpdateTransaction = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
        cnUpdateTransaction.Open();
        cnUpdateTransaction.
        //cnUpdateTransaction.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception Ex)
{

}
```

Here i am opening 10000 instances of connection objects and just leaving it for garbage collection. Now as they are unmanaged objects and i am not calling close or dispose then finally how this objects will be released. Whether operating system will do something for this and when. Please share your with some document link for this issue.

Comment: You are following bad practices by: initializing a variable to "" and then immediately setting it to something else; by not implementing `using` blocks; and by including your connection string in the code and then posting the code (hint: change  your database password **now**).

Comment: I am aware of all things what you have said, but code written here is very basic and its intend is just to know how this unmanaged connection objects will be released if we open unmanaged connection multiple times and didn't call dispose or close method. Also I haven't seen any finalizer implemented for this class (SqlConnection) in C#

Answer (score 0):

When implementing `IDisposable` and the class has unmanaged resources you should implement a Finalizer that calls the `Dispose` method.  That way if the user of the class fails to call `Dispose` unmanaged resources will (eventually) be released when the GC runs.  See [Implement IDisposable correctly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for a good example.

If the object contains references to unmanaged resources and does not contain a finalizer and `Dipose` is not called then that memory will not be reclaimed automatically.  Basically, there is a memory leak.  The memory won't be reclaimed until the process is shut down.  See [Identify And Prevent Memory Leaks In Managed Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163491.aspx) for some interesting reading.

Comment: It is true that implementing finalizer will release unmanaged resource but what i want to know is that if we didn't implement finalizer with dispose not explictily call dispose then what happened of that unmanaged objects, how it will be released. What operating system does to clear such objects